# what's the different between <br> and \n as line break

Tags: javascript, html, line-breaks

I just finished a very simple assignment from my class. The part of the wrong code of script I wrote is like this:

```
alert("The circumference of a circle with this radius is " + circum + 
    "<br>" + "The area of a circle with this radius is " + area + "\n" + 
    "The surface area of a sphere with this radius is " + surarea + "\n" + 
    "The volume of a sphere with this radius is " + volume + "\n");
```

I have tried both `<br>` and `\n` in this part of code, and I am pretty sure that other parts are all right since I have tested them.

I was just wondering why the `<br>` doesn't work for me on my program. The example that the teacher gave us seems working fine. But he also told us that `<br>` should be used in HTML while `\n` is used in JS.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Think of it as, if an HTML rendering engine will be reading your text to display, it will understand the `<br>`. Anything else out of it will require using `\n` which is the newline feed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\n` is a linebreak character. It is interpreted like that by the JS compiler. The HTML parsers on the other hand treat it as a normal string.

`<br>` in html is a tag to introduce a line break. In JS strings, this is treated as a normal string.

Answer (score 2):

\n is a new line feed within the context of plain text 
while `<br>`

is line break within the context of HTML

Comment: yep, that's where I got lost lol. maybe it's because of I'm writing js inside html file... that misled me.

Answer (score 1):

The `<br>` or `<br />` tag is an `HTML` element that will display everything after this `<br>` or `<br />`  by starting from new line when rendered in browser while the `\n` is used to jump to next line in the source code or the output prompt in standard output.

Comment: @WeiWU welcome anytime. I added extra info for those who may not know, I'm sure you know the details and wanted to know details deep down to exact technical reasons.

Answer (score 1):

`<br> and <br />` are HTML and XHTML tags, while \n is a newline in code.